# Content server search function doenst work

Tags: opentext

keep getting this search error in opentexts content server anyone knows how to fix it
[the error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9JyG.png)

keeps happening when using the search bar

also says error get results failed when using the search bar

everything seems to be working fine and it works in the quality

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.